# Pagination Based on Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to implement pagination on my Django app that is based on the filtered queries, but the pagination shows all the objects even the ones not filtered, any insight on what I'm doing wrong?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
def searchPropertyListView(request):
city = City.objects.all().annotate(
    num_property=Count("property")).order_by("-num_property")

categories = Category.objects.all()
purposes = Purpose.objects.all()

featured = list(Property.objects.filter(featured=True))
shuffle(featured)

querySet = Property.objects.all()
city_or_neighborhood = request.GET.get('city_or_neighborhood')
category = request.GET.get('category')
purpose = request.GET.get('purpose')


if city_or_neighborhood != '' and city_or_neighborhood is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(Q(city__title__icontains=city_or_neighborhood)
                                | Q(neighborhood__title__icontains=city_or_neighborhood)
                                ).distinct()
if category != '' and category is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(category__title=category)
if purpose != '' and purpose is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(purpose__title=purpose)

paginator = Paginator(querySet, 1)

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    querySet = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    querySet = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    querySet = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: This looks fine. You should check that those if statement branches are being hit and if they are, that the filtering does what you expect it to.

Comment: Django version?

Comment: Django version 3.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paginator.get_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_page) is New since Django 2.0.

```
def searchPropertyListView(request):
    ...
    Your code here
    ...

    paginator = Paginator(querySet, 1)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
```

**And html**

```
{% for property in page_obj %}
    
    {{ property.city.title }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

See [Using Paginator in a view function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function)